# Django - 404 static in Docker on react app

Tags: django, docker, saleor

I have backend on Django and storefront/dashboard on React.

Django in docker container.

Dockerfile (Django)

```yaml
### Build and install packages
FROM python:3.8 as build-python

RUN apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get install -y gettext \
  # Cleanup apt cache
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements_dev.txt /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

### Final image
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN groupadd -r saleor && useradd -r -g saleor saleor

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
  libxml2 \
  libssl1.1 \
  libcairo2 \
  libpango-1.0-0 \
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
  shared-mime-info \
  mime-support \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /app/media /app/static \
  && chown -R saleor:saleor /app/

COPY --from=build-python /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
COPY --from=build-python /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ARG STATIC_URL
ENV STATIC_URL ${STATIC_URL:-/static/}
RUN SECRET_KEY=dummy STATIC_URL=${STATIC_URL} python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

EXPOSE 8000
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "4", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "saleor.asgi:application"]
```

When I go to the Dashboard and access objects with pictures, I get error:

[error on Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlidC.png)

Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to go into production keeping your images in the volatile container volume is NOT a good idea. How are you starting the container ? if you are running this for testing and or development just use the saleor platform docker-compose https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-platform